# looping through a dropdown menu using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to loop through a dropdown menu on at this url: https://www.accuform.com/safety-sign/danger-danger-authorized-personnel-only-MADM006

So, for example, the first dropdown menu - under options - lists out different materials and I want to select each one in turn and then gather some other information from the webpage before moving on to the next material. Here is my current code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.accuform.com/safety-sign/danger-danger-authorized-personnel-only-MADM006')

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id('x-mark-icon').click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('Wiqj7mb4rsAq9LB'))
options = select.options
optionsList = []

driver.find_elements_by_class_name('select-wrapper')[0].click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Wiqj7mb4rsAq9LB']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)


for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

for optionValue in optionsList:
    print("starting loop on option %s" % optionValue)
    # select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='Wiqj7mb4rsAq9LB']")))
    # select = Select(select)
    select.select_by_value(optionValue)
```

I started with just the loop, but got this error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

I then added the webdriverwait and get a TimeoutException error.

I then realized I should probably click on the wrapper in which the dropdown is held, so I added the click, which does pup up the menu, but I still got the TimeoutException.

So I thought, maybe I should move to the element, which I tried with the action chain lines and I got this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined
```

I tried to avoid that error by using this code instead:

```
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Which just resulted in the timeoutexception again.

I pretty new to Python and Selenium and have basically just been modifying code from SO answers to similar questions, but nothing has worked.

I'm using python 3.6 and the current versions of Selenium and firefox webdriver.

If anything is unclear or if you need more info just let me know.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Based on the answer and comments by  Kajal Kunda, I've updated my code to the following:

```
`material_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select- 
dropdown']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_dropdown)

materials=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.select-wrapper 
ul.dropdown-content li")



for material in materials:

    # material_dropdown = 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select-dropdown']")

    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_dropdown)

    # materials=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.select-wrapper ul.dropdown-content li")

    material_ele=material.find_element_by_tag_name('span')

if material_ele.text!='':

    material_ele.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dataPriceDisplay")

    print(price.text)`
```

The result is that it successfully prints the price for the first type of material, but then it returns: 
`StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <li class=""> is stale;...`

I've tried variations of having the hashed out lines in and outside of the loop, but always get a version of the StaleElementReferenceException error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the whole thing with `requests`. Grab the drop down list from the options listed in drop down then concatenate the `value` attributes into requests url that retrieves json containing all the info on the page. Same principle applies for adding in other dropdown values. The ids for each drop down selection are the `value` attributes of the options in the drop down and appear in the url I show separated by `//` for each drop down selection.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.accuform.com/product/getSku/danger-danger-authorized-personnel-only-MADM006/1/false/null//{}//WHFIw3xXmQx8zlz//6wr93DdrFo5JV//WdnO0RpwKpc4fGF'
startURL = 'https://www.accuform.com/safety-sign/danger-danger-authorized-personnel-only-MADM006'

res = requests.get(startURL)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
materials = [item['value'] for item in soup.select('#Wiqj7mb4rsAq9LB option')]
sizes = [item['value'] for item in soup.select('#WvXESrTyQjM3Ciw option')]
languages = [item['value'] for item in soup.select('#WUYWGMePtpmpmhy option')]
units = [item['value'] for item in soup.select('#W91eqaJ0WPXwe9b option')]

for material in materials:
    data = requests.get(url.format(material)).json()
    soup = bs(data['dataMaterialBullets'], 'lxml')
    lines = [item.text for item in soup.select('li')]
    print(lines)
    print(data['dataPriceDisplay'])     
    # etc......
```

---

Sample of JSON:

[image]

Comment: Thanks QHarr, while this seems like an interesting approach, I'm not really interested in moving to a different package. I've been learning Selenium for a bit now and don't want to start over with beautifulsoup. Even though it may be better, I'm in the middle of this project and it doesn't seem like a good time to start over.

Comment: No worries. I’ll see what answers are here by tomorrow and perhaps I’ll add a selenium answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.It should work.

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.accuform.com/safety-sign/danger-danger-authorized-personnel-only-MADM006')

    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('x-mark-icon').click()

    material_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select-dropdown']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_dropdown)

    #Code for material dropdown
    materials=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.select-wrapper ul.dropdown-content li")


    material_optionsList = []
    for material in materials:
        material_ele=material.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
        if material_ele.text!='':
          material_optionsList.append(material_ele.text)

    print(material_optionsList)

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_dropdown)


    size_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@class='select-dropdown'])[2]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size_dropdown)

    #Code for size dropdown
    Sizes=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.select-wrapper ul.dropdown-content li")
    size_optionsList = []
    for size in Sizes:
        size_ele=size.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
        if size_ele.text!='':
            size_optionsList.append(size_ele.text)



driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", size_dropdown)
```

Output :

```
[u'Adhesive Vinyl', u'Plastic', u'Adhesive Dura-Vinyl', u'Aluminum', u'Dura-Plastic\u2122', u'Aluma-Lite\u2122', u'Dura-Fiberglass\u2122', u'Accu-Shield\u2122']
```

Hope you will do the remaining.Let me know if it works for you.

**EDIT** Code for loop through and get the price value of materials.

```
for material in range(len(materials)):
    material_ele=materials[material]

    if material_ele.text!='':
       #material_optionsList.append(material_ele.text)
       #material_ele.click()
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_ele)
       time.sleep(2)
       price = driver.find_element_by_id("priceDisplay")
       print( price.text)
       time.sleep(2)
       material_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='select-dropdown']")
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", material_dropdown)
       materials = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.select-wrapper ul.dropdown-content li")
       material+=2
```

Output :

```
$8.31
$9.06
$13.22
$15.91
$15.91
```

Comment: Rather than just rewriting the OP's entire script and dropping it in an answer, it would be nice for the OP and future readers if you would explain what you changed and why so others can learn from it.

Comment: @JeffC - You are right.I should mentioned what i have done.I have just changed the locator and mouse hover on the element but I am not sure whether it would work every time.

Comment: You need to put that description in the answer itself. Not everyone reads all comments, nor should they have to to fully understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks Kajal, but I'm trying to loop through the materials, size, etc. dropdowns, not the shop by category one. I tried to modify your code to work with one of those, but I keep getting a nosuchelementexception with this line: "element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[class='caret']")"

Comment: Your xpath is wrong.When you pass any attribute you should use `@` . `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='caret']")` Now try.

Comment: I have modified my code.Hope that helps you to get items from dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Kajal Kundu! That got a lot of the way there, but as I note in the edit to my original post, I can get the script to print the price for the first material, but then get a StaleElementReferenceException. If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: @JarodJacobs: I have udpated my answer with edited part.Please check the edited part of my answer.Please accept my answer if this helps.

Comment: @KajalKundu, Thanks for the update! Unfortunately, all it is doing is printing the first price and then stops without any error message. I think I understand all of the code in your update except for the last line. What is material+=2 doing. It looks like a counter, but I don't see where it is initiated. Thanks for all the help! I will definitely mark this as the right answer once I can get it working.

Comment: When I check materials length count it gave me 16.However total element in the drop down box is 8 that means after each element there is new line to skip the new line I have increased counter 2.But it should work.I have got output.

Comment: Just add diver.maximize_window()  after driver.get(url) see if you get any difference.

Comment: @KajalKundu I'm afraid I just can't get the same result as you. I copied and pasted your code exactly, but always just get the first price printed out.

Comment: have you done driver.maximize_window() after diver.get(url)

Comment: yep, it successfully maximizes the window size, but nothing else changes